# Bivariate K function (splancs package) - Kenv.tor returning "Inf" in $upper

Tags: r

I am using splancs package to compute bivariate (cross) k function and running into problems with the simulation where the Kenv.tor$upper will contain "Inf" as values. Does anyone know if this is a true effect of the data or whether the function itself is having a problem with the data?

I have Kenv.tor structured such that

Kenv.tor(X1, X2, Polygon, 30, s)

where X1 contains 25302 points, X2 contains 432 points, and s = seq(20, 2640, 100).

Just looking for any insight as to why the upper limits would be so high and if there is anything I can do to make the function work with my data. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you made sure all your points are strictly inside your polygon? If you sample down your data (you've a lot of X1) does it still happen? Does it happen in odd places or at the start, end, grouped in the middle? Probably my 20 year old code...

Comment: Sounds like division by zero. Seems that having the data would be needed.

Comment: Spacedman-I have checked that all points fall within the polygon. It does not happen in odd places, it is always at the end and the values approaching "inf" are typically exponentially high as well. I have had some success sampling X1 down to about 4-5000 but only if I also reduce X2 proportionally. Thank you for responding!